# XML Serialization with SAX parser

Tags: xml, serialization, sax

I am looking at Xerces for XML processing for my project. What I need is to serialize the XML using that library.

Looking at the documentation and on the web I see that the library have DOM Serializer. Now I have to use SAX parser to work with XML.

The question is: Will I still be able to use DOM Serializer class to read/write my XML? If yes, then at the very least the name is confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, apparently there are 2 separate thing: DOM as a Document Object Model and DOM as a DOM parser.

I just wish they would be named differently. ;-)